# Mongodb in CDAP

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am a new user at CDAP.
I follow [Learn CDAP: MongoDB to CDAP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGaKB.png) Youtube tutorial video, but when I click run, It will return error:

"Spark program 'phase-1' failed with error: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]. Please check the system logs for more details."

Why I take this error, I did anything like official tutorial Youtube video and my mongodb service is running well

[My Mongodb config CDAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGaKB.png), [My JS func in CDAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akfxx.png), [My CDAP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12xVj.png), [My database info in mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPL51.png), [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPbyv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question is some months old and the poster probably moved on, but for future readers I got this error as well, so for what it's worth:

In my case, it was because I had not set up the VPC Network Peering. The Dataproc cluster the jobs are run on are created in a separate network and it needs access to the network where your Mongo servers are located.

In general, make sure that you have followed the "Creating a Private Instance" guide, specifically the [Set up VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip#set_up_network_peering) and probably also the [Create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip#create_a_firewall_rule) sections. This will allow the cluster access to the rest of your network and the DB servers in it.